# Getting All User Info from REST API in WSO2

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, claims

For getting user info in wso2 sso, im using bellow api:

https://localhost:9443/oauth2/userinfo?schema=openid

the result is like this:

```
{
    "sub": "mahyar.z",
    "family_name": "Zarif Kar Asli",
    "email": "mahyar.z@mtnirancell.ir"
}
```

But i expect more claims. In **Service Provider** -> **Claim Confiquration** i added some local claim dialect. In user profile list i can see these claims but in JSON result from api just some of them are appeared.

Im using AD as user store, and i added local claim that is mapped with AD user attributes. For example i added http://wso2.org/claims/custom/company claim that is mapped with **company** attribute in AD.
I can see user company in User Profile but it is not in JSON result, as you can see.

So how can i get all user info's?

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is:

1. Place the claims you want to return in the dialect wso2.org/oidc/claim (Add External Claim)
2. Add Claims to Service Providers -> Claim Settings -> Claims Requested -> Add Claim URIs
3. Edit adding claims in Registry -> Browse -> Tree -> _system / identity / oidc -> Properties / openid